# Android Architecture Component: How to cancel Retrofit Request?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have implemented the Structure (UI,ViewModel,Repo,Data Source) in my code base. And a problem brings when I want to cancel the request in Retrofit.

My constraint is:

1. I need to track the event when the user cancel the request
2. When the fragment/activity is dismissed by user( Let's say the lifecycle is in onDestroy), it will be treated as cancel action.

And under this structure (Using the NetworkBoundResource also have no control to cancel the Request) , how can I cancel my request in retrofit?

Appreciate any comment or answers, or if there is better implementation to resolve this issue, I will give a it try.

MyViewModel.java

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private Repo repo;

    MyViewModel(Repo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public void cancelAllRequest(){
        repo.cancelAllRequest();
    }

}
```

Repo.java

```
public class Repo{
   private APIService apiService;

   public LiveData<File> getFile(int id){
       //Retrofit
       MutableLiveData<File> data = new MutableLiveData<>():
       Observable<User> observable= apiService.getFile(id);
       observable.subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
       return data;
   }

   public LiveData<File> postFile(File file){
       //Retrofit
       MutableLiveData<File> data = new MutableLiveData<>():
       Observable<User> observable= apiService.postFile();
       observable.subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
       return data;
   }

   public void cancelAllRequest(){
       //how to get the subscription and unsubscribe it
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can cancel Retrofit Request.

Use [cancel()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#cancel--) method to cancel a request.

and [isCanceled()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#isCanceled--) will help  you to determine the request is already cancel or not.

```
    callWithCancel = apiService.getDataFromDynamicUrl(url);

    callWithCancel.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Timber.i("Request unsuccessful" + response.errorBody().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            if (call.isCanceled()) {

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

To cancel

```
if (callWithCancel != null){
   callWithCancel.cancel();
}
```

You can maintain a list or queue for all of your request.Add every request to the queue. When any request is successful remove that request from list or queue. So You list and queue will always contain pending request. So you can easily cancel all request when you need.

```
   public void cancelAllRequest(){
      //how to get the subscription and unsubscribe it
      while(!isEmpty()){
        requestQueue.remove();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Feel Sorry to miss the Observable code I used in the code base. Is it still work with this solution?

Comment: yes its worked. you just have to call `call.cancel()` . Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: But How can I get the "call" from Repo.java since I only got the Observable from API

Comment: Are you using RxAdapters instead of Retorfit adapter?

Comment: Don't know how you organized your code. For simplicity create a `Queue` in `Application` class so that you can access from anywhere.

Comment: Yup, I am using RxJavaCallAdapterFactory. Does it have any conflict with this solution?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1216 . Observable `unsubscription` will cancel your Request.

Comment: It seems I need to create a list of the subscriber to unsubscribe them, and also the tag I need to add for the specific request cancel. Anyway, thanks for your effort and I will try to implement better to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Call `dispose()` on the disposable object you get in the onSubscribe method.

```
downloadSubscription.dispose();
```

Comment: Feel Sorry to miss the Observable code I used in the code base. Is it still work with this solution?

Comment: @LongRanger Updated the answer with a solution using Observable.